# Left coset always equals right coset false proof

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

This is from Dummit and Foote Algebra book second edition.

I understand the proof but doesn’t this imply that $gK=Kg$ so left and right cosets always coincide? I know this is not true but if $X=gK$ and $Kg=X$, then $Kg=gK$ for all $g$ but this is not true in general. What Am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right that this proposition does imply that the left and right cosets of $K$ agree. You're also right that this is not true in general, but the key is that $K$ is the kernel of a group homomorphism. In fact, this property of the subgroup $K$ is called normality. It turns out that being normal (right cosets and left cosets agreeing) is equivalent to being the kernel of a group homomorphism. Another equivalent form of this is that the set of cosets $G/K$ forms a group under $(gK)(hK) = ghK$.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept your answer when I can. It really helped

Answer (score 1):

As $K=Ker(\varphi)=\varphi^{-1}(\{1\})$, and $\varphi$ is a homomorphism, it follows that

$\varphi^{-1}(uk)=\varphi^{-1}(u)\varphi^{-1}(k)=\varphi^{-1}(u)=\varphi^{-1}(k)\varphi^{-1}(u), \forall u\in X, k \in K$.

The left and right cosets therefore coincide, and the subgroup is thus called *normal*.